# Why does the following code not shift the current date forward by five days in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, getdate

I am learning the Date class in JavaScript and am trying to move the current date forward by five days with the following code:

```
      var today = new Date();
      today = today.setDate(today.getDate() + 5);
```

However, when I run the code I get an extremely long number. Can anyone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: assigning `today` the return value of `setDate` is causing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This should be enough:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate() + 5);
```

... as you modify object stored in `today` anyway with `setDate` method.

However, with `today =` in place you assign the *result* of `setDate` call to `today` instead - and that's the number in milliseconds, according to [**docs**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.36):

> ```
> Date.prototype.setDate(date)
> [...] 
> 4. Let u be TimeClip(UTC(newDate)).
> 5. Set the [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property of this Date object to u.
> 6. Return u.
> ```

Apparently, that number becomes a new value of `today`, replacing the object stored there before.

Comment: To clear things up, the issue is that date objects are modified when calling date methods on them. There is no need to reassign your date already-created date object (the today variable), otherwise unexpected results occur.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And `Date` objects are far from being unique in that aspect (among JS native objects).

Answer (score 0):

The *setDate* function updates your object with the correct time. You should do

```
var d = new Date()
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 5);
```

The d object will have the current date plus five days.

Another way is to use the *setTime* function. This function accepts as parameter the number of milliseconds since 1969 (the "Epoch" in UNIX time). Correspondingly, the *getTime* function returns the current date in milliseconds since the Epoch.

To add 5 days to the current date you need to add 5 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, that is, 5 times 24 hours (3600 seconds) times 1000.

```
var d = new Date()
d.setTime(d.getTime() + 5 * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
```

Note that your object will be updated and you don't need to watch for the return of neither *setTime* of *setDate*.